# Casting at compile time

Tags: c, casting, unions

Consider the following union:

```
/**
 * @brief   Holding parameter 16-bit value variant representation
 */
typedef union
{
    uint16_t    u;  /*!< unsigned integer 16-bit */

    int16_t     i;  /*!< signed integer 16-bit */

} hparamValue_t;
```

And this function that takes such a union as an input parameter:

```
void hparam_set(const hparamValue_t value);
```

When calling this function, I have only an `uint16_t` or `int16_t` at hand. So to use it in a "clean" way, I do:

```
uint16_t myVar; // somewhere

// when calling the function
hparamValue_t hpv;
hpv.u = myVar;
hparam_set(hpv);
```

But I am more leaning into this construct:

```
hparam_set(*((hparamValue_t*)&myVar));
```

While it doesn't look too obvious, it doesn't force me to create an additional, artificial variable. The question is, would the cast to pointer and then value be unfolded still at compile time? This seems safe, anything I am missing?

Comment: What is hparam_set() supposed to do? You've already set the union with hpv.u = myVar;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing an object using a different type than it is defined with, we have to consider the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

`hparam_set(*((hparamValue_t*)&myVar));` conforms to this rule since `hparamValue_t` is a union type that includes a member with the same type as `myVar`. A second rule to consider is that when a pointer to one object type is converted to a pointer to another object type, the C standard does not define the behavior if the pointer being converted does not have the alignment required for the new type. In the case of a pointer to a `uint16_t` being converted to a pointer containing only 16-bit members, the alignment requirement of the union is the same as the alignment requirement of `uint16_t` in ordinary C implementations, but the C standard does not require this.

Another way to pass a `hparamValue_t` to `hparam_set` is by using a compound literal:

```
hparam_set((hparamValue_t) { .u = myVar });
```

A compound literal has the form `(type) { initializers }`. The `initializers` have same form as initializers in a definition. A compound literal is an unnamed object of the designated type. Outside a function, it has static storage duration. Inside a function, it has automatic storage duration the same as an ordinary object defined at the same location.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You stated: `For an object defined with type uint16_t, the type hparamValue_t is not any of the types listed above.` but before that `an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union),`. How is it not that?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: My mistake, you are right. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I have noticed this would work as well: `hparam_set((hparamValue_t) {myVar});`- I am guessing it just maps the memory here and not care about explicit assignement? But still, isn't this approach the same as manually assigning to a temporary variable in terms of computation speed/ number of steps?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: Re “I am guessing it just maps the memory here”: The compound literal creates a new object; it does not map or overlap memory with the object whose value is used to initialize it.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: Re “But still, isn't this approach the same as manually assigning to a temporary variable in terms of computation speed/ number of steps?”: Compilers optimize. To pass an argument to a function, the compiler has to create a copy of the value. If you pass `*((hparamValue_t*)&myVar)`, the compiler has to create a copy of the `hparamValue_t` that is accessed. If you pass the compound literal, the compiler has to create that. I would expect any halfway decent optimizer to generate the same code.

Comment: What I meant more is that the compiler does not complain that I am assigning a `uint16_t` type to `hparamValue_t` type. But you sort of answer my second question- this approach creates a new object on the stack. And Ok, I guess it would be optimized out. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253026/discussion-between-lukasz-przenioslo-and-eric-postpischil).